# Qt c++ как попасть в нужный блок QTextEdit и взаимодействовать с текстом

Tags: c++, qt

Я делаю функцию как при слиянии в git, где она выделяет строки, и в сроке выделяет символы не схожие с предыдущим слиянием. В цикле при не совпадении букв вызывается функция, которая должна закрасить эти буквы по их индексу, в строке где они не совпадают. Буквы цветом закрашиваются, но только в первой строке, дальше первого блока курсор не спускается. Помогите!!!

Этим кодом я хочу попасть в 3 блок, а то есть на 3 линию. Но ничего не выходит курсор все там же на 1 строке

```
QTextCursor cursor = QTextCursor(ui->textEditgggg->document());
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfBlock, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 3);
```

Сто лет уже пытаюсь найти ответ на этот вопрос, не проходите мимо!))

Comment: QTextCursor::StartOfBlock 4 Move to the start of the ***current*** block. QTextCursor::NextBlock 16 Move to the beginning of the next block.

Comment: Но это не работает, я бы не задавал сюда вопрос не читая документацию. @SergeyTatarincev